# UI not being updated even after state being changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  const [searchedCourses, setSearchedCourses] = useState([]);
```

```
  const handleSearch = (event) => {
        searchCourses(event.target.value, 1, 6);

    }
```

```
async function search(query, page = 1, limit = 20) {
  if (!query) {
    return {
      data: [],
      pagination: {},
      links: {},
    };
  } else {
    return get(`/api/search?query=${query}&page=${page}&limit=${limit}`);
  }
}
```

```
const searchCourses = async(query, page, limit) => { 
  const searched = await search(query, page, limit);
  
  for(let item of searched.data) {
      let duplicated = checkDuplicate(item);
      if(duplicated) {
          item.status = duplicated.status;
          item._id = duplicated._id;
      };
  }

  setSearchedCourses([...searched.data]);
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
      getAllCourses();
  }, [searchedCourses]);
```

```
{searchedCourses.length > 0 && searchedCourses.map((course, index) => {
    return ( <div key = {index}>
                            <Box 
                                course = {course}
                            </Box>
                        </div>
    );
})}
```

I have used useState and when handleSearch function is being triggered, it will call the asynchronous searchCourses function. This function calls another asynchronous function called search and returned value will be stored in const searched variable.
Then I check if there is duplicate between "courses", which is another array state, and "searched". If there is, we modifies the "searched.data" accordingly. After modifying process is over, I use setter method for state to set searchedCourses and I also have useEffect that detects the change of searchedCourse.
However, the ui does not re-render unless I trigger handleSearch function once again. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your example first has `searchedCourses` being initialized as an array but then you follow it up by calling it as a function. Is this intentional or did you mean `setSearchedCourses`?

Comment: I have searchedCourses, which is state that was being initialized as an array, and I have a function called searchCourses without "ed" which I call in handleSearch function.

Comment: Can you make a code sandbox?